# Sort by list in list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of this type :

```
l = [{"id":"21", "region" :['2', '6', '4']}, {"id":"12", "region" :['1', '3', '8']}]
```

I want to sort the list on the "region" field, and that also at 2nd index.
that is :

```
l = [{"id":"21", "region" :['2', **'6'**, '4']}, {"id":"12", "region" :['1', **'3'**, '8']}]
```

How do I do it ? I am aware of itemgetter. But couldn't do with that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list.sort()` with key argument, passing a lambda expression to the key argument -

```
In [45]: l = [{"id":"21", "region" :['2', '6', '4']}, {"id":"12", "region" :['1', '3', '8']}]

In [46]: l.sort(key=lambda x: x['region'][1])

In [47]: l
Out[47]:
[{'id': '12', 'region': ['1', '3', '8']},
 {'id': '21', 'region': ['2', '6', '4']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to `sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)`

```
>>> l = [{"id":"21", "region" :['2', '6', '4']}, {"id":"12", "region" :['1', '3', '8']}]

>>> print sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['region'][1], reverse=False)
[{'region': ['1', '3', '8'], 'id': '12'}, {'region': ['2', '6', '4'], 'id': '21'}]

>>> print l
[{'region': ['2', '6', '4'], 'id': '21'}, {'region': ['1', '3', '8'], 'id': '12'}]
```

Comment: You do not need the `reverse=False` , its `False` by default. Just an FYI.

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes, I know. I just wanna hint at the asker  in case he needs to sort descending.